# How to set Transactions manually in Jmeter

Tags: transactions, jmeter

I am trying to run a performance test for client-side (In Mobile devices with cloud solutions) and server-side at the same time using Jmeter. For EX: I have a selenium script (in client-side) that executes login script and returns the UX Page load time. Similarly, HTTP requests on the server-side return the page load time. I would like to print both the values in Jmeter summary reports.

Like

1. AndroidLoginTime
2. Server login Time (Typically I used Transaction controller for this)

What I understand **"Jmeter Summary results"** has the avg, max and min time of executed HTTP requests time. In the above case, I already have average time which got it by a cloud solution. Now I would like to print the same value in Jmeter results.

I have done this in **LoadRunner** by using the command and got the summary report like below

lr_set_transaction(LoginTime, txTime, LR_PASS);

[image: Sample LoadRunner summary report]

Is there any way we can do this in Jmeter.

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is adding a [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/) where you can set desired transaction name (Sampler label) and the response time

[image]

The results can be observed by any [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) of your choice, i.e. [Summary Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. This is the solution I was looking for.